# How to write test for the HTML element being passed as a prop to a component a and a function is being called from that

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I need to the unit test for the kind of code that follows. How to write the test for the same.

How to trigger the handler function that has to stimulate the click from the Button passed to the footer prop of Popover

```
const React, {Component} from 'react';
const {Popover, Button} from 'slds'; // Any UI library

class My Component extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Popover
                footer={
                    <div>
                        <Button
                        onClick={() => {this.props.handler()}}
                        >
                        Close
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                }
            >
                <Button>POP</Button>
            </Popover>
        )
    }
}
```

Need to mock the handler function, and check whether it's being called. Using jest and enzyme.

```
/* Inside Test */

const handler = jest.fn();
// creating a wrapper
const wrapper = shallow(<Mycomponent handler={handler} />);
// How TO STIMULATE THE CLICK NOW
......
?????

// At last
expect(handler).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can add some sort of class name or unique identifier inside your component, in this case I added claddName to it:

```
<Button
  onClick={() => {this.props.handler()}}
  className="my-fancy-button">
   Close
</Button>
```

In your test you can do something like this:

```
/* Inside Test */
const handler = jest.fn();
// creating a wrapper
const wrapper = mount(<Mycomponent handler={handler} />); // <----------- replace shallow with mount
// How TO STIMULATE THE CLICK NOW
wrapper.find('.my-fancy-button').simulate('click');
// At last
expect(handler).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

If not you can also target the element directly by `wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');`

Comment: I tried targeting button element directly, it won't work. And now tried this also. It's also not working. I think this might be because these elements are passed in a prop.

Thanks of the response

Comment: In that case can you switch to `mount` instead of `shallow` and see if it shows up in wrapper. You can inspect content of the wrapper by using `console.log(wrapper)`

Comment: Works for the `mount`. Thanks, Rikin

Comment: @Lokeshsp I updated answer, you can accept it if it you like.

Answer (score 0):

If we are passing some HTML elements for the components like `Popover` or `Modal`. We need to make sure they are **open** by passing necessary props like `isOpen=true` and have to use `mount` instead of `Shallow`.

If you don't have a proper selector to find the component, pass an id to the element in the component and find with that `id`